# How do i create macroses for paging up and paging down in Adobe Reader?

Tags: adobe-reader

I'm reading a book in `Adobe Reader` and i'm trying to quiz myself at the end of each chapter and then check the answers for correctness but i have to scroll up and scroll down every time which is annoying.
How do i switch between pages quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *build-in* technique which goes like this:

Being on a page you are reading, type the number of the page which contains the answers to the topic you are willing to test yourself, go to that page and after that, you can use:

`Alt + left arrow` or `Alt + right arrow`

to switch between two pages(previous and current one) quickly.